# What if I write return statement in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, return-value, return, return-type

What if I write return statement in constructor? Is it standard conformant?

```
struct A
{ 
     A() { return; } 
};
```

The above code compiles fine, without any error at [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/fmpsg). But the following code doesn't:

```
struct A
{ 
   A() { return 100; } 
};
```

It gives this error at [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/50kxf):

> error: returning a value from a constructor

I understand that returning value from constructor doesn't make sense at all, because it doesn't *explicitly* mention return type, and we cannot store the returned value after all. But I'm curious to know :

- Which statement from the C++ Standard allows the first example  but forbids the second one? Is there any *explicit* statement?
- Is the return *type* in the first example `void`?
- Is there any *implicit* return type at all?

Comment: I'm not going to voluntarily reread the standard, but I'll venture a guess regarding the motivation for allowing an empty return: if a constructor has branches or loops, then sometimes it is nice to be able to `return` out. If `return` was never allowed, then developers would probably just `goto` to a label defined at the bottom of the function.

Comment: It is more than that. You can `return` out of _any_ function or method, special or not.

Comment: Constructors conceptually have a signature taking `T* this` as an invisible argument and returning `void`. So you can always `return;` to bail out mid-function.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, using return statements in constructors is perfectly standard.

Constructors are functions that *do not return a value*. The family of functions that *do not return a value* consists of: void functions, constructors and destructors. It is stated in 6.6.3/2 in the C++ standard. The very same 6.6.3/2 states that it is illegal to use `return` with an argument in a function that does not return a value.

> **6.6.3 The return statement**
>
> **2** A return statement without an
>   expression can be used only in
>   functions that do not return a value,
>   that is, a function with the return
>   type void, a constructor (12.1), or a
>   destructor (12.4). A return statement
>   with an expression of non-void type
>   can be used only in functions
>   returning a value; the value of the
>   expression is returned to the caller
>   of the function.

Additionally, 12.1/12 states that

> **12.1 Constructors**
>
> **12** No return type (not even void) shall
>   be specified for a constructor. A
>   return statement in the body of a
>   constructor shall not specify a return
>   value.

Note, BTW, that in C++ it is legal to use `return` with an argument in a void function, as long as the argument of `return` has type `void`

```
void foo() {
  return (void) 0; // Legal in C++ (but not in C)
}
```

This is not allowed in constructors though, since constructors are not void functions.

There's also one relatively obscure restriction relevant to the usage of `return` with constructors: it is illegal to use `return` in function-try-block of a constructor (with other functions it is OK)

> **15.3 Handling an exception**
>
> **15** If a return statement appears in a
>   handler of the function-try-block of a
>   constructor, the program is ill formed.

Comment: In addition, as long as they do not return a value, having a return statement in a constructor is perfectly fine.

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE: Yeah, that's basically what it says in the first sentence of 6.6.3/2 quoted above.

Comment: I think the standard does not say that constructors and destructors are functions, so "family of functions [...] consists of [...] constructors, destructors" might be inaccurate before C++.

Comment: @phresnel: The standard defines [some] constructors and destructors as "special member *functions*".

Comment: @phresnel: ... Good point although. I can't find anything more conclusive that would explicitly state that constructors in general are member functions.

Comment: If a constructor returns nothing what happens to the caller? Does it still get an object?

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps the notion of having typeless return in constructors is to control the termination of constructor function.

```
struct A
{ 
// more definitions     
A() 
{ 
if( !goodToGoOn)  
 return;
// the rest of the stuffs go here
} 
};
```

Comment: Yup, this is basically what I did today, which was the first time I realised we can even do this!

Comment: Precisely. Returning a value in a non returning function, just causes the return command to disregard the returning parameter and just return. In other words, "return 0;" just gets compiled as "return;" i.e. it exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor by definition does return something.

For the code below,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class dog{
    private:
        string _name;
        string _breed;
    public:
        //initialise private variables to those passed in
        void init(string name, string breed)
        {
            _name = name;
            _breed = breed;
        }

        void bark(){cout << "BARK! BARK! My name is " << getName() << "\n";}

        string getBreed(){return _breed;}
        string getName(){return _name;}
    };

//can run with
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //create a dog named Sally
    dog sally;
    //Initialise its variables
    sally.init("sally", "chocolate lab");
    sally.bark();
}
```

Here we create a void type function that initializes our dog object, then in our main function we must call that init function on our new dog object.But if use a constructor our code looks instead like

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class dog{
    private:
        string _name;
        string _breed;

    public:
        //Dog constructor to initialize passed in variables
        dog(string name, string breed){
            _name = name;
            _breed = breed;
        }

        void bark(){cout << "BARK! BARK! My name is " << getName() << "\n";}

        string getBreed(){return _breed;}
        string getName(){return _name;}
};

//can run with
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //create a dog named Sally
    dog sally("sally", "chocolate lab");
    sally.bark();
}
```

This code does essentially the same thing but it is to show that a constructor initializes the passed in variables and returns the object itself.

You cannot say

```
dog(string name, string breed)
    {
        _name = name;
        _breed = breed;
        return cout << "BARK! BARK! My name is " << getName() << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: A constructor does *not* return something of "type void". It cannot, because the `void` type is an incomplete type that cannot be completed.

Comment: I guess its better to say that it HAS type void?