# how to make a constructor to return in between?

Tags: c++

I mean something like this

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class A{
            int a, b;

            public:
            A(int a,int b, int *c);
    };

    A::A(int x, int y, int *errcode)
    {
            *errcode = 0;
            a=x;
            b=y;

            // check for some error conditions
            // and return from the constructor
            if (y==0)
            {
              *errcode=-1;
              return;
            }

            // some more operations

            return;
    }

    int main() {

            int errorcode;

            A(1,0,&errorcode);

            cout << errorcode;

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You tried it and what "doesn't work"? I would, however, likely restructure it to omit all `return`s though.

Comment: Related: ["using return statements in constructors is perfectly standard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255777/what-if-i-write-return-statement-in-constructor#:~:text=Yes%2C%20using%20return%20statements%20in,do%20not%20return%20a%20value.&text=2%20A%20return%20statement%20without,or%20a%20destructor%20(12.4)).

Answer (score 18):

To handle errors in constructor you should throw an **Exception**.
By throwing an exception you can handle the condition where object creation is not complete by just returning there would be no way to indicate that the object creation was successful or some error condition occurred.

**[This](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8)** C++ FAQ is a good read for you.

Comment: What if he didn't want to return an error? What if he wanted to return early from the constructor because the constructor had finished it's work?

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Do you mean, You would want to continue using an object that was not completely formed? That would be a bad idea.

Comment: yes, the imho evil part is the returning of a value. the return-statement itself in the middle of the constructor as a result of some conditions is perfectly ok.

Comment: An object is fully formed once the constructor body has been **entered**. Leaving the constructor body early via return does not mean you have a partially formed object.

Comment: @john: Not quite. An object is fully formed when the constructor body exits normally, either by falling out the bottom or hitting a `return`. If it leaves by an exception, the object officially never existed. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm

Comment: @Fred Larson: Yes good point. I'm glad I didn't mention exceptions because I had it wrong in my head. So if an exception in the constructor no destructor call for the object itself (but one for all it's sub-objects).

Comment: @Als: when `return` would simplify control flow in other functions, you can use it in the constructor too, [like in this stupid example](http://ideone.com/lVx9h).

Comment: @Ken Bloom: There is no debate of whether it is syntactically valid or not, it is perfectly valid. The point is what purpose it serves? Apart from demonstration example codes, there is no practical use of it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want

```
*errcode = 0;
```

Instead of

```
errcode = 0;
```

Otherwise you are setting the errcode pointer to `0`

EDIT:

You could also simplify your code a bit by using references instead of pointers:

```
A::A(int x, int y, int &errcode)
{
        errcode = 0;
        a=x;
        b=y;

        // check for some error conditions
        // and return from the constructor
        if (y==0)
        {
          errcode=-1;
          return;
        }

        // some more operations

        return;
}
```

And in your main()

```
A(1,0,errorcode);
```

Comment: i.e right, it was a small typo, ... But i wanted to check, whether this kind of programming practice is right in C++? Any inputs will be really helpful..

Comment: @pdk: Als answered that quite well.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to use a `return` statement, just like you have done here. (This is specified by section 12.1/12 of the standard). You can't give a value to return, though -- returning from a constructor is like returning from a `void` function.

---

One small problem in your code is the `errcode = 0` statement. I think you meant `*errcode = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

When you can, avoid having code that could goes wrong in constructors.
But, if you have no other choices :

- Use a member to check if the new object is well-formed
- Use a factories to build complexes objects
- Use an initialization function

In any cases, avoid throwing exceptions from constructors/destructors as that is often a source of leaks.

Comment: The last statement is grossly incorrect. **It should say, For failing constructors, always throw exceptions** & **For destructors, never ever throw exceptions**.

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference.

```
A::A(int x, int y, int& errcode){

//check error
errcode = 0;
}

int errorcode;
new A(1,2,errorcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in using return statement in constructor. Another approach could be grouping constructor implementation inside do..while loop and break if error happens. e.g.

```
A::A(){
  do{
    //if error
    break;
  }while(0);
}
```