# checking iterator type in a container template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am writing a container class, and want to provide a constructor taking iterators as parameter, but only if the underlying iterated type matches the container type.

So I wrote:

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    template <typename InputIter>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type, typename T>>::type
    Buffer(InputIter first, InputIter last)
    {
    }
};
```

But I have compilation errors saying the template argument 1 and 2 are invalid

What is wrong?

Code with compiler here : https://onlinegdb.com/SyIqN_mBG

Comment: constructor should not return any type and if it is not a constructor it shouldn't have the same name as a class where it is contained...

Comment: OK I see, I have copy/pasted the enable_if line from another example without figuring out that at the ends it returns a type. But then, I can't find how to enable a constructor with enable_if

Comment: for future reference please post the error message

Comment: @W.F. Actualy in the standard, constructors are conceptualy members with no name (so it is not possible to call them using class member access )[\[class.ctor\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/special#class.ctor-1): *Constructors do not have names.*

Comment: @Oliv true indeed, though you can't have a function with a name of the class that contains it, can you? :)

Comment: @W.F. A member function has a return type and a name. If it has no name, so it is just the return type. Actualy it is not that neither, since saying "it has no name" is probably just to ensure it can not be accessed with the dot operator, but I tend to remember it this way, and I consider the class name inside constructor declarator to be the return type.

Comment: @Oliv Well strictly speaking constructor **does not** return any type. If it would one couldn't use return statement in it... [\[see also\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255777/what-if-i-write-return-statement-in-constructor)

Comment: @W.F. I know that, as I said you is just to remember it and for esthetical reasons : I always add a line break between function return type and function name, for constructor I after the class name, I find this more consistent and clearer.

Comment: @Oliv `constructor should not return any type and if it is not a constructor it shouldn't have the same name as a class where it is contained...` sorry I honestly do not follow - to which part of my comment your response apply?

Comment: @W.F. Just to say you that I know that the class name before the parameter list inside the constructor declarator is neither its name nor its return type. Nevertheless for esthetical reasons I prefer to consider (and this is realy personal) that the class name correspond to a return type during code formating. For constructors, I add a line break between the class name and the parameter list as for functions I add a line break between the return type and the function name. This is just a matter of taste, I find the code much more readable this way (I do a lot of meta programming).

Answer (score 8):

Almost there. What you need to remember, as you were told in comments, is that constructors don't have return types. The usual trick of SFINAE on the return type won't work on them.

But they can have additional template parameters, ones that are always defaulted anyway, but the mere existence of can be used for SFINAE. So let's use that very test you provided (after adding a missing `::value`) to add a non-type template parameter to the c'tor:

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    template <typename InputIter, 
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type, T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    Buffer(InputIter first, InputIter last)
    {
    }
};
```

So if the iterators are proper, we have an additional `int = 0`, and if they aren't, SFINAE! The c'tor is removed from the set of overloads.

Comment: I usually write something like: `template<typename InputIter, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type, T>::value>::type>`; however this will not work if there are multiple otherwise identical templates (in your version, the type, e.g. `int`, can be varied to support this case).

Comment: @ArneVogel - IIRC when the conditions are mutually exclusive, you don't even need to vary the type. That's why I took to favoring this approach. I could be misremembering however.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this even works with [more than two cases](https://ideone.com/MddnqG)! Being a compiler writer can't be easy…

Answer (score 5):

SFINAE has 3 usable places:

- as return type
- as parameter type
- as template type

For constructor, you cannot use return type.

I suggest default template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    template <typename InputIter,
              typename std::enable_if<
                           std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type,
                                        T>::value,
                                      bool>::type = false>
    Buffer(InputIter first, InputIter last)
    {
    }
};
```